# Create C shared library at the installation time of Rubygem - Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shared-libraries, bundler

I have written a [gem](https://github.com/lasandun/minimization/tree/opencl) which can be installed with Bundler. There is a FFI interface to a C program, therefore I have to generate the shared library at the installation time.

I have added a [Makefile](https://github.com/lasandun/minimization/blob/opencl/lib/opencl/Makefile) to do so. I need to know a better way to call it at the installation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to run a Makefile at install time is through the [`extconf.rb`](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/#extconfrb) file in your gem. Here are som useful links:

- [RubyGems Guides – Gems with Extensions](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/)
- [Aaron Patterson – Writing Ruby C Extensions (Part 1)](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/12/18/writing-ruby-c-extensions-part-1.html)
- [Aaron Patterson – Writing Ruby C Extensions (Part 2)](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2010/12/11/writing-ruby-c-extensions-part-2.html)
- [Yorick Peterse - Hacking extconf.rb](http://yorickpeterse.com/articles/hacking-extconf-rb/)

Comment: hey...thank you for the answer. I see extconf.rb will create the makefile. When is the makefile being called? If I wrote the makefile on my own, it there a way to call it? Isn't that a standard way?

Comment: You could write it manually and just copy it in the `extconf.rb`. I added another blog post in my answer.